# filter_var() accepts invalid URL

Tags: php, filter-var

Why does `filter_var()` accepts and validate this URL **`http://http://www.google.com`**?

```
$website = "http://http://www.google.com";

echo filter_var($website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); // This outputs the value of $website
```

I think this is wrong. Any solution or fixed for this?

**`phpinfo()`**

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the url is wrong?

Comment: @zerkms There are two `http://`'s.

Comment: Oops, my attention was stolen by `com.ph` in the end )

Comment: How about checking if URL exists?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you've found a bug in PHP.  The PHP manual states that FILTER_VALIDATE_URL validates uris according to http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html

If you read the spec, PHP obviously fails to properly validate per the guidelines.  Specifically, in section 3 (URI Syntactic Components), it's defined that the scheme (http in your case) may only exist once, and precedes the only colon in the uri.

You should report this bug at https://bugs.php.net/

Good work finding it!